# call excel 2010 vba from bash menu

Tags: microsoft-excel, bash, vba

I am writing a `bash` menu function and am having trouble calling a `VBA` written in excel 2010, from within it. The first line is the path to the `VBA`. When the uer selects ngs I am trying to have the xlsx with the `vba` open so it can be executed. Thank you :).

```
ngs() {
call {C:\Users\cmccabe\Desktop\Sanger\NGS_Sanger.xlsx}
cd 'C:'    C:/Users/cmccabe/Desktop/Python27/
for file in  C:/Users/cmccabe/Desktop/Python27/*_sanger.txt
do
cat $file >>  c:/Users/cmccabe/Desktop/Python27/out.txt
done
convert
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it. For anyone with a similar question here is the solution:

```
cmd /C "start c:\\path\\to\\where\\file_is\\filename"
```

Hope this helps and thank you :).